# How does the Apple Watch get the temperature?

Tags: iphone, temperature, apple-watch, watchos

The Apple Watch shows the temperature on the clock face.

When my Apple Watch is disconnected from my iPhone, the temperature display becomes disabled, but the time is still displayed. That leads me to think the watch doesn't have a temperature sensor, but it getting it from the Internet.

My question is: **How does the Watch get the temperature?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The temperature shown does come from the Weather App. Small bits of data on the watch face are known as complications.

Tapping the temperature on the watch face will open the Weather app thus revealing the source of the data. The watch gets the data from your iPhone which, in turn, uses location and data from the Internet. 
You may find more useful information in the [Apple Watch User Guide](https://help.apple.com/watch/#/).

Answer (score 4):

The Apple watch doesn't have a temperature sensor for external temperature.

It probably uses the same web service as the Weather app.

Comment: I would be astounded if the watch didn't have at least one thermocouple. My guess is they are for maintaining the charge rate and CPU in check but they wouldn't be ideal for measuring ambient temperature so close in thermal contact with a body. You might also be right that there are no temp sensors at all in the small device. I would bet good money the current conditions display is driven by location data and internet data - so the main point is +1

Comment: Agreed 100%.  It 's gotta have at least one.

Comment: There seems to be one. I recall a video in which an Apple Watch was immersed in boiling water. Temp sensor registered overheating.

Comment: I wasn't precise enough, I meant for external temperature. There is definitely one for the processor temp like in every recent processor.

Comment: Possibly, but I'm wondering how it would compensate for body temperature being placed on the wrist.

Answer (score -2):

My watch updates temp when disconnected from iPhone. I've tested it

Comment: Curious: Disconnected, unpaired or out of range? Have you found further documentation?